# Stop a go routine before starting a new one

Tags: go

Got a server that handles requests from clients. Each requests spins up a go routine in a for loop, how do I stop a previous go routine before a new one starts.

```
for {
    select {
    case discoveryRequest := <-discoveryRequestChannel:

        
        for _, resourceNames := range discoveryRequest.ResourceNames {
            accumulatedResourceNames = append(accumulatedResourceNames, resourceNames) //resources requested are accumulated
        }

        log.Infof("request resources: %v", accumulatedResourceNames)

        secret, err := s.MakeSecretResponse(accumulatedResourceNames, nonce)
        if err != nil {
            log.Error(err) // Handling all the errors from the above layers. no need for context as they are provided in previous layers.
            continue
        }
        if err := stream.Send(secret); err != nil {
            log.Errorf("Error when sending stream to envoy %v ", err)
        }
        version = secret.VersionInfo
        
        secretsRenewEndChannel <- true
        close(secretsRenewEndChannel)
        log.Info("kill switch")
        go s.SecretsRenewer(version, accumulatedResourceNames, secretsRenewChannel, secretsRenewEndChannel)
        isSecretRenewRunning = true
        log.Info("set to true")
        secretsRenewEndChannel = make(chan bool)
```

Comment: If you are trying to limit the use of goroutines, start one goroutine before the loop and send it requests through a channel. Or, you can wait until the first goroutine terminates (you need two channels, one to trigger term, the other to notify the caller the goroutine is returning), and then start a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't clear. Why do you need to `select` like this in a loop? What are you selecting amongst? You can just receive from the channel instead.

---

You may be looking for a worker pool here. Here's an example [from gobyexample](https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func worker(id int, jobs <-chan int, results chan<- int) {
    for j := range jobs {
        fmt.Println("worker", id, "started  job", j)
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        fmt.Println("worker", id, "finished job", j)
        results <- j * 2
    }
}

func main() {

    const numJobs = 5
    jobs := make(chan int, numJobs)
    results := make(chan int, numJobs)

    for w := 1; w <= 3; w++ {
        go worker(w, jobs, results)
    }

    for j := 1; j <= numJobs; j++ {
        jobs <- j
    }
    close(jobs)

    for a := 1; a <= numJobs; a++ {
        <-results
    }
}
```

To adjust it to your problem, the `worker` would handle requests and the main goroutine would feed requests into a channel. You can easily control how many goroutines run concurrently with this approach.

---

Another pattern that may be useful in your case is [rate limiting](https://gobyexample.com/rate-limiting)

Comment: while i agree with this answer, please consider that a write to j is not linked to a read to results. In other words if many routines write to j, then the results read from results are unordered. The proper pattern is to push an input containing the return channel per request

Comment: @mh-cbon: there are many variations on this solution, I just presented the simplest one. In many cases ordering isn't required. In many other cases, results are self identifying (e.g. it's clear from a result which request it belongs to). Providing separate return channels is possible but it does complicate the code, and I'd prefer to start with the simplest viable solution.